# Real name (Full name) of USB device?

Tags: c#

DriveInfo[] mydrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

```
 if (mydrive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
```

in this way i get all the devices that connected to my machine
 and their name :  mydrive.Name
 can i know which kind of device is each one of them?-
 like DOK , external HDD and so on..... 
 or to get their real name like- MyBook (the name of the external HDD)-
 it will also help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.driveinfo%28VS.80%29.aspx):

You can get the Volume Label from the DriveInfo : Drive_Info.VolumeLabel

Another useful link about all [information available from DriveInfo](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hirendra_singh/2284/Default.aspx).